# Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\imageloadfont()

Tags: laravel

Why does the php function imageloadfont not working on php version 8 and laravel 9

Is there a new way to call php built-in functions inside laravel controllers?

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Session\Store;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class CaptchaController extends Controller{
    public function createCaptcha() {
        $font = imageloadfont(asset('public/captcha/04b.gdf'));
```

It produces an error

```
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\imageloadfont()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick a backslash in front: `\imageloadfont(asset('public/captcha/04b.gdf'));`

Comment: now its not under the App\Http\Controllers\ Call to undefined function imageloadfont()

Comment: You need to make sure you have `php-gd` installed.

Comment: Thanks, I just need to install the php-gd, but this answer is correct just add backslash in the method